# Cancel query on refetch in apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to build a small widget with some inputs and cards that contain data which is recalculated on the backend using `react` and `apollo`. Cards contain a loader to indicate that request is in progress.

Whenever I change an input, I want to trigger a request to backend, which takes a long time (due to computation) - around 30 seconds.

When you input data - mutation is triggered via one apollo client, but right afterwards it triggers a query to another apollo client, which takes 30 seconds or so.

In that time it is possible to update input again - and in that case, I would like to cancel the previous request and trigger a new one.

This is the query

```
  const {
    data,
    loading,
    refetch,
    networkStatus,
  } = useCalculationQuery({
    widget_id: widgetId,
    skip: !isCalcTriggered,
  });
```

Code for `useCalculationQuery`

```
function useCalculationQuery({ widget_id, skip }: Options = {}) {
  const { teamId } = ... ;

  const query = useQuery(QUERY_CALCULATION, {
    skip,
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    variables: {
      team_id: teamId,
      widget_id,
    },
    client: apolloCalculations,
  });

  return query;
}
```

And this is the fetch function

```
  async function handleCalcFetch() {
    if (isCalcTriggered) {
      setIsFetchInProgress(true);
      await refetch();
      setIsFetchInProgress(false);
    }
    if (!isCalcTriggered) {
      setIsCalcTriggered(true);
    }
  }
```

As you can see - with `isCalcTriggered` flag I skip the query execution until `handleCalcFetch` is called. Then I set the flag, and on every other call except the first I do `refetch`.

These other flag (`isFetchInProgress` which is set with `setIsFetchInProgress`) is to indicate that request is in place, because after calling refetch, networkStatus is always `7` rather than `4`. That's issue number one.

Issue number two is that I want to cancel previous requests whenever I hit `refetch()`, so that I am sure I always get the newest data, which now is not the case.